# Minimal Perl/Gtk2 telnet client

Tags: perl, telnet, gtk2

This is a bare-bones telnet client, using Gtk2 and Perl's Net::Telnet.

Incoming text is displayed, but typed commands can't be sent to the server. Either the server is not receiving typed commands or we aren't receiving the server's response.

The code for handling typed commands is pretty simple:

```
$cmd = $entry->get_text();       # Gtk2::Entry

$telnetObj->put(                 # Net::Telnet
    String => $cmd,
    Telnetmode => 0,        
);
```

Nevertheless, this script is completely non-functional. Any ideas why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Minimal telnet client

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk2 '-init';
use Net::Telnet;

# Connect to any old MUD
my $host = 'dead-souls.net';
my $port = 8000;
# The Net::Telnet object
my $telnetObj;

# Open a Gtk2 window, with a Gtk2::TextView to display incoming text, and a Gtk2::Entry for sending
#   commands    
my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title('Minimal telnet client');
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_default_size(600, 400);
$window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub {

    Gtk2->main_quit();
    exit;
});

my $vPaned = Gtk2::VPaned->new();
$window->add($vPaned);
$vPaned->set_position(350);

my $scrollWin = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new(undef, undef);
$vPaned->add1($scrollWin);
$scrollWin->set_policy('automatic', 'automatic');     
$scrollWin->set_border_width(0);

my $textView = Gtk2::TextView->new;
$scrollWin->add_with_viewport($textView);
$textView->can_focus(FALSE);
$textView->set_wrap_mode('word-char');
$textView->set_justification('left');
my $buffer = $textView->get_buffer();

my $entry = Gtk2::Entry->new();
$vPaned->add2($entry);
$entry->signal_connect(activate => sub {

    # When the user enters a command, empty the entry box and (if the connection is open), send the 
    #   command to the host, and display the command in the textview
    my $cmd = $entry->get_text();
    $entry->set_text('');

    if ($telnetObj) {

        $telnetObj->put(
            String => $cmd,
            Telnetmode => 0,        
        );

        my $iter = $buffer->get_end_iter();
        $textView->get_buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($iter, $cmd . "\n");
        Gtk2->main_iteration() while Gtk2->events_pending();
    }
});  

$window->show_all();   

# Set up a main loop
my $id = Glib::Timeout->add(100, sub{ &mainLoop($telnetObj, $textView, $buffer) });
if (! $id) {

    exit;
}

# Open the connection
$telnetObj = Net::Telnet->new(
    Timeout => 15,
);

$telnetObj->open(
    Host        => $host,
    Port        => $port,
    Errmode     => sub { &disconnected(); },
);

# Start Gtk2's main loop
Gtk2->main();

# ##################################################################################################

sub mainLoop {

    my ($telnetObj, $textView, $buffer) = @_;

    my $text = $telnetObj->get(
        Errmode => sub { },
        Timeout => 0,
    );

    if ($text) {

        # We've received some text from the host. Display it in the textview
        my $iter = $buffer->get_end_iter();
        $buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($iter, $text);
        Gtk2->main_iteration() while Gtk2->events_pending();
    }

    return 1;
}

sub disconnected {
    print "Disconnected\.\n";
    exit;
}

sub connectError {
    print "Connection error\.\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with other hosts?

Comment: Yes, I've tried at least a dozen hosts, and I've also tried those hosts with other telnet clients, to make sure the hosts are operational.

Comment: I replaced the method `put(...)` with `cmd(String => $cmd);` and had a conversation, created user name and password, etc.  But with a big bad "glitch": every command I sent timed out first, and only then did I see the response. All that was shown in the window. I don't know why it times out -- perhaps you should be waiting for some particular sequence in their return? (This can then be a reason why `put` fails?)

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions above, there are at least three working solutions to replace the faulty:

```
    $telnetObj->put(
        String => $cmd,
        Telnetmode => 0,        
    );
```

And they are:

```
# This works:
$telnetObj->put(
    String => $cmd . "\n",
    Telnetmode => 1,        
);

# This also works:
$telnetObj->cmd(
    String => $cmd,
    Timeout => 0,
);

# This also works:
$telnetObj->print($cmd);
```